React - Framer Motion - Cannot get Layout prop to work properly
The layout prop is the most frustrating prop in Framer Motion. I have 2 lists. One of them will leave the DOM when all of its children are deleted. I need 2 things from it, for it to leave the DOM gracefully, and for its brother to move into its new position in style.
I always thought that you add Layout to the parent element, so that if any changes occur inside, the children will transition accordingly.
Inside my List, I have the LI working harmoniously with AnimatePresense. So I delete a child, it will animate out, then the neighbour will slide up.
Now I want to replicate the same behaviour with the UL, so once all the children are deleted, it animates out and its brother slides to the centre. So far I have been successful into doing one or the other.
In the below version I went as far as turning every single element into a motion element, including the fragment, adding layout to all of them, and nothing worked. I have cleaned it up to default since then.
export default function UserPortal(user: User) {
  const { id, bookings, ...userDetails } = user;
  const { item } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.modal);
  const validate = useValidate({ update: { userId: id } });
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  function handleLogout() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 125);
    dispatch(logout());
    dispatch(clearForm());
  }

  return (
    <motion.section
      initial={{ y: -100 }}
      animate={{ y: 0 }}
      transition={{ duration: 0.6, type: 'easeInOut' }}
    >
      <section className={css.portal}>
        <div className={css.col}>
          <h2>Details</h2>
          <List className={css.user} items={Object.entries(userDetails)} keyFn={([key]) => key}>
            {([key, value]) => (
              <p>
                <span>{key}</span>
                <Input id={key as keyof FormData} savedData={value} />
              </p>
            )}
          </List>
          <button onClick={validate}>SAVE</button>
        </div>
        <>
          <List className={css.bookings} items={bookings} keyFn={({ id }) => id}>
            {(booking) => <BookedItem {...booking} />}
          </List>
          <Modal>
            <EditBooking id={id} {...item} />
          </Modal>
        </>
      </section>
      <button className={css.logout} onClick={handleLogout}>
        LOGOUT
      </button>
    </motion.section>
  );
}

interface ListProps<T> {
  items: T[]; 
  keyFn: (item: T) => string | number; 
  className: string; 
  children: (item: T) => JSX.Element;
}

export default function List<T>({ items, keyFn, className, children }: ListProps<T>) {
  return (
    <AnimatePresence>
      {items.length > 0 && (
        <motion.ul
          className={className}
          initial='hidden'
          whileInView='visible'
          viewport={{ once: true }}
          exit={{ opacity: 0, scale: 0.8 }}
        >
          <AnimatePresence>
            {items.map((item, index) => (
              <motion.li
                layout
                key={keyFn(item)}
                variants={{
                  visible: { opacity: 1, scale: 1 },
                  hidden: { opacity: 0, scale: 1.2 },
                }}
                exit={{ opacity: 0, scale: 0.8 }}
                transition={{ type: 'tween', duration: 0.5, delay: index * 0.1 }}
              >
                {children(item)}
              </motion.li>
            ))}
          </AnimatePresence>
        </motion.ul>
      )}
    </AnimatePresence>
  );
}

Now in this version, I can get the transition to work. Instead of turning the 2nd section into a motion section and adding layout, I have to turn the adjacent brother to a motion.div and add layout to this, also a transition to slow down the animation. However, as a result I had to remove AnimatePresense from the UL, which means though it transitions, as the last child in the UL is deleted, it vanishes immediately and whichever way you look at it, its still bad. I have to decide over one bad animation, or another bad animation
export default function UserPortal(user: User) {
  const { id, bookings, ...userDetails } = user;
  const { item } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.modal);
  const validate = useValidate({ update: { userId: id } });
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  function handleLogout() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 125);
    dispatch(logout());
    dispatch(clearForm());
  }

  return (
    <motion.section
      initial={{ y: -100 }}
      animate={{ y: 0 }}
      transition={{ duration: 0.6, type: 'easeInOut' }}
    >
      <section className={css.portal}>
        <motion.div layout className={css.col} transition={{ duration: 1 }}>
          <h2>Details</h2>
          <List className={css.user} items={Object.entries(userDetails)} keyFn={([key]) => key}>
            {([key, value]) => (
              <p>
                <span>{key}</span>
                <Input id={key as keyof FormData} savedData={value} />
              </p>
            )}
          </List>
          <button onClick={validate}>SAVE</button>
        </motion.div>
        <>
          <List className={css.bookings} items={bookings} keyFn={({ id }) => id}>
            {(booking) => <BookedItem {...booking} />}
          </List>
          <Modal>
            <EditBooking id={id} {...item} />
          </Modal>
        </>
      </section>
      <button className={css.logout} onClick={handleLogout}>
        LOGOUT
      </button>
    </motion.section>
  );
}

AnimatePresense had to be removed from the UL in order for layout to work upstairs. However, in the LI, both layout and AP work harmoniously, I delete a child element, it animates out first, then the next child moves up.
export default function List<T>({ items, keyFn, className, children }: ListProps<T>) {
  return (
    <> 
      {items.length > 0 && (
        <motion.ul
          className={className}
          initial='hidden'
          whileInView='visible'
          viewport={{ once: true }}
          exit={{ opacity: 0, scale: 0.8 }}
        >
          <AnimatePresence>
            {items.map((item, index) => (
              <motion.li
                layout
                key={keyFn(item)}
                variants={{
                  visible: { opacity: 1, scale: 1 },
                  hidden: { opacity: 0, scale: 1.2 },
                }}
                exit={{ opacity: 0, scale: 0.8 }}
               transition={{ type: 'tween', duration: 0.5, delay: index * 0.1 }}
              >
                {children(item)}
              </motion.li>
            ))}
          </AnimatePresence>
        </motion.ul>
      )}
    </>
  );
}

